# How do I put a semi transparent layer on my form

Tags: delphi, transparency

I have read some questions about this in the last week or so, on stackoverflow.

My requirement is more or less the same.

I need to put a semi-transparent layer on top my form, but this form may have several other components: Lists, Edits, Labels, Images ,etc

I need this semi-transparent layer to be on top of all that.

The idea is to fade areas of the form that the use those not, or cannot access in that moment.

I use Delphi 2007.

Thanks

Comment: So you want some of the controls to be 'hidden', while some are to be visible (and clickable)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an demo app using an alpha blended transparent TForm as the fade shadow.  The main difference between this and Andreas's example is that this code handles nested controls and does not use any window regions.

[image: Normal]

[image: Shadowed]

MainForm.pas:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Shadow;

type
  TShadowTestForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Button5: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Shadow: TShadowForm;
    procedure WMMove(var Message: TWMMove); message WM_MOVE;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ShadowTestForm: TShadowTestForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TShadowTestForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(Shadow) then
  begin
    Shadow := TShadowForm.CreateShadow(Self);
    Shadow.UpdateShadow;
    Button1.Caption := 'Hide Shadow';
    Button4.Caption := 'Show Modal Form';
  end else
  begin
    FreeAndNil(Shadow);
    Button1.Caption := 'Show Shadow';
    Button4.Caption := 'Test Click';
  end;
end;

procedure TShadowTestForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('clicked ' + TControl(Sender).Name);
end;

procedure TShadowTestForm.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tmpFrm: TForm;
begin
  if Assigned(Shadow) then
  begin
    tmpFrm := TShadowTestForm.Create(nil);
    try
      tmpFrm.ShowModal;
    finally
      tmpFrm.Free;
    end;
  end else
    Button2Click(Sender);
end;

procedure TShadowTestForm.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TShadowTestForm.Create(Self).Show;
end;

procedure TShadowTestForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if not (fsModal in FormState) then
    Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TShadowTestForm.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(Shadow) then Shadow.UpdateShadow;
end;

procedure TShadowTestForm.WMMove(var Message: TWMMove);
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(Shadow) then Shadow.UpdateShadow;
end;

end.
```

MainForm.dfm:

```
object ShadowTestForm: TShadowTestForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Shadow Test Form'
  ClientHeight = 243
  ClientWidth = 527
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PopupMode = pmExplicit
  Position = poScreenCenter
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnResize = FormResize
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Tag = 1
    Left = 320
    Top = 192
    Width = 97
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Show Shadow'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 64
    Top = 56
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Test Click'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 192
    Top = 40
    Width = 289
    Height = 105
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 2
    object Button3: TButton
      Left = 24
      Top = 16
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Test Click'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = Button2Click
    end
    object Button4: TButton
      Tag = 1
      Left = 72
      Top = 72
      Width = 129
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Test Click'
      TabOrder = 1
      OnClick = Button4Click
    end
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Tag = 1
    Left = 24
    Top = 151
    Width = 233
    Height = 84
    Caption = 'Panel2'
    TabOrder = 3
    object Button5: TButton
      Tag = 1
      Left = 22
      Top = 48
      Width = 155
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Show NonModal Form'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = Button5Click
    end
  end
end
```

Shadow.pas:

```
unit Shadow;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs;

type
  TShadowForm = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FBmp: TBitmap;
    procedure FillControlRect(Control: TControl);
    procedure FillControlRects(Control: TWinControl);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate); message WM_MOUSEACTIVATE;
    procedure WMDisplayChange(var Message: TMessage); message WM_DISPLAYCHANGE;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor CreateShadow(AForm: TForm);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure UpdateShadow;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TShadowForm.CreateShadow(AForm: TForm);
begin
  inherited Create(AForm);
  PopupParent := AForm;
  FBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  FBmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
end;

destructor TShadowForm.Destroy;
begin
  FBmp.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TShadowForm.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBmp);
end;

procedure TShadowForm.FillControlRect(Control: TControl);
var
  I: Integer;
  R: TRect;
begin
  if Control.Tag = 1 then
  begin
    R := Control.BoundsRect;
    MapWindowPoints(Control.Parent.Handle, PopupParent.Handle, R, 2);
    FBmp.Canvas.FillRect(R);
  end;
  if Control is TWinControl then
    FillControlRects(TWinControl(Control));
end;

procedure TShadowForm.FillControlRects(Control: TWinControl);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Control.ControlCount-1 do
    FillControlRect(Control.Controls[I]);
end;

procedure TShadowForm.UpdateShadow;
var
  Pt: TPoint;
  R: TRect;
begin
  Pt := PopupParent.ClientOrigin;
  R := PopupParent.ClientRect;

  FBmp.Width := R.Right - R.Left;
  FBmp.Height := R.Bottom - R.Top;

  FBmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;
  FBmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, FBmp.Width, FBmp.Height));

  FBmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := TransparentColorValue;
  FillControlRects(PopupParent);

  SetBounds(Pt.X, Pt.Y, FBmp.Width, FBmp.Height);
  if Showing then
    Invalidate
  else
    ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
end;

procedure TShadowForm.WMDisplayChange(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  UpdateShadow;
end;

procedure TShadowForm.WMMouseActivate(var Message: TWMMouseActivate);
begin
  Message.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;

end.
```

Shadow.dfm:

```
object ShadowForm: TShadowForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Cursor = crNo
  AlphaBlend = True
  AlphaBlendValue = 128
  BorderStyle = bsNone
  Caption = 'Shadow'
  ClientHeight = 281
  ClientWidth = 543
  Color = clBtnFace
  TransparentColor = True
  TransparentColorValue = clFuchsia
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PopupMode = pmExplicit
  Position = poDesigned
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

ShadowDemo.dpr:

```
program ShadowDemo;

uses
  Forms,
  ShadowTestForm in 'MainForm.pas' {ShadowTestForm},
  Shadow in 'Shadow.pas' {ShadowForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TShadowTestForm, ShadowTestForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: In the "UpdateShadow" in the line R.Width, TRect - R those not have "Width" or  "Height". I use D2007. How can we get the ClientRect?

Comment: `TRect.Width` simply subtracts `TRect.Left` from `TRect.Right`, and `TRect.Height` subtracts `TRect.Top` from `TRect.Bottom`. I adjusted the code to show that.

Answer (score 11):

Create a new VCL project. Add a few sample buttons and other controls to the main form. Create a *new* form, set `AlphaBlend` to `true` and `AlphaBlendValue` to `128`. Perhaps `Color = clSkyBlue` will suffice? Then add the following procedure to your main form:

```
procedure TForm1.UpdateShadow;
var
  pnt: TPoint;
  rgn, rgnCtrl: HRGN;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(Form2) then Exit;
  Form2.Show;
  pnt := ClientToScreen(Point(0, 0));
  Form2.SetBounds(pnt.X, pnt.Y, ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
  rgn := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Form2.Width, Form2.Height);
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    if Controls[i].Tag = 1 then
    begin
      if not (Controls[i] is TWinControl) then Continue;
      with Controls[i] do
        rgnCtrl := CreateRectRgn(Left, Top, Left+Width, Top+Height);
      CombineRgn(rgn, rgn, rgnCtrl, RGN_DIFF);
      DeleteObject(rgnCtrl);
    end;
    SetWindowRgn(Form2.Handle, rgn, true);
    DeleteObject(rgn);
end;
```

and call this on resize,

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateShadow;
end;
```

and form move:

```
procedure TForm1.WMMove(var Message: TWMMove);
begin
  inherited;
  UpdateShadow;
end;
```

Finally, set the `Tag` to `1` on the controls (on your main form) that are to be accessible.

[image: Sample screenshot]
<sub>(source: [rejbrand.se](http://privat.rejbrand.se/shadowWithHoles.png))</sub>

**Hint:** You might also wish to set the `Cursor` of the 'shadow form' to `crNo`.

Comment: You know - this opens some possibilities for me (I'm currently disabling components that I want to make read-only but it doesn't look right.)

Comment: Regions are so Win2k ;-) Instead of using a region, make use of an alpha channel instead. Create an in-memory 32-bit bitmap that is the desired dimensions and have it contain your desired fade color as the background. Then apply an alpha value to all of its pixels, where the faded areas are partially blended and the areas corresponding to the accessible controls are fully transparent. Use the Win32 API `UpdateLayeredWindow()` function to apply that bitmap to Form2's window.

Comment: Alternatively, draw the bitmap onto Form2's `Canvas` in the `OnPaint` event, and then use Form2's `TransparentColor...` and `AlphaBlend...` properties together to accomplish the same effect. Instead of using the bitmap's alpha channel, make the transparent pixels use a different color instead and then assign that color to the form's `TransparentColorValue` property. The faded pixels will just be normal colored pixels.

Comment: Perfect. It's really more that hope for. Thanks

Comment: @Leonardo. Yes I am doing the same read-only assign, with this it's much less code, and more visual.

Comment: One problem !? The form I need to put this layer "in" is a Modal form. So the layer is always behind it.

Comment: How can I do mode or less the same without the TForm? My Goal is to shad some components like images and TPanels.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, please! (example) :-)

Comment: @Jlouro: why not just display the faded TForm modally on top of your normal modal TForm?  Multiple TForms can be modal at the same time. If that does not suit your needs, then you will likely have to use `CreateWindowEx()` directly to create a plain Win32 API window and overlap it on top of your modal TForm, setting the TForm as the parent so it can't go behind the TForm window.

Comment: @Jlouro: or you can use a normal `TForm` and set its `PopupParent` property (I forget if D7 has that property) or override its `CreateParams()` method, to set the modal TForm as the parent window (from the API perspective, not the VCL perspective). That will prevent it from disappearing behind the modal TForm.

Comment: I made up a demo and was almost ready to post it here when the IDE crashed and wiped out the project.  I'll make up another demo and get it posted here in a bit.

Comment: I have posted the source of a demo app.