# Create a transparent bitmap and UpdateLayeredWindow

Tags: delphi, winapi, graphics, bitmap, alpha

I'm trying to create a mask window with "loading" text, to alert the user about a busy state of my application.

For this, I first created a single form with:

- BorderStyle = bsNone
- Color = clBlack
- AlphaBlend = True
- AlphaBlendValue = 180;

As the second step, I want to create another Form, but this one will has dynamic content.
I need to create a transparent bitmap with some status text and use the UpdateLayeredWindow to draw the window as the text.

Take a look and my desired result:

[image]

Remember: the text will be different in some cases, like:

- Recalculating
- Loading resources
- Loading report

That's the reason what I need a dynamic bitmap generation.

**QUESTION**

How can I create a transparent bitmap with text and use it on a form with UpdateLayeredWindow?

I'm trying this, but without success ( to try the code put a Button5 and Label2 on a form):

```
  procedure Inc(var p: pointer);
  begin
    p := Pointer(Integer(p) + 1);
  end;

var
  s: string;
  frm: TForm;
  f: HFont;
  tx: HDC;
  bmp, old: HBITMAP;
  rc: TRect;
  h: BITMAPINFOHEADER;
  pvBits: Pointer;
  t: tagBITMAPINFO;
  x,y: integer;
  a, r, g, b: byte;
  sz: TSize;
  p: tpoint;
  BlendFunction: TBlendFunction;
begin
  tx := CreateCompatibleDC(0);


  s := label2.Caption;
  f := SelectObject(tx, label2.Font.Handle);


  fillchar(rc, SizeOf(rc), 0);
  DrawText(tx, PChar(s), length(s), rc, DT_CALCRECT);

  fillchar(h, SizeOf(h), 0);
  pvBits := nil;

  h.biSize := SizeOf(h);
  h.biWidth := rc.Right - rc.Left;
  h.biHeight := rc.Bottom - rc.Top;
  h.biPlanes := 1;
  h.biBitCount := 32;
  h.biCompression := BI_RGB;

  FillChar(t, SizeOf(t), 0);
  t.bmiHeader := h;

  bmp := CreateDIBSection(tx, t, 0, pvBits, 0, 0);
  old := SelectObject(tx, bmp);
  if old > 0 then
  begin
    SetTextColor(tx, $00FFFFFF);
    SetBkColor(tx, $00000000);
    SetBkMode(tx, TRANSPARENT);

    DrawText(tx, PChar(s), length(s), rc, DT_NOCLIP);

    r := GetRValue($FF);
    g := GetGValue($FF);
    b := GetBValue($FF);

    for x := 0 to h.biWidth-1 do
      for y := 0 to h.biHeight-1 do
      begin
        a := Byte(pvBits^);

        Inc(pvBits);
        Byte(pvBits^) := (b * a) shr 8;
        Inc(pvBits);
        Byte(pvBits^) := (g * a) shr 8;
        Inc(pvBits);
        Byte(pvBits^) := (r * a) shr 8;
        Inc(pvBits);
        Byte(pvBits^) := a;
      end;

    SelectObject(tx, old);
  end;

  SelectObject(tx, f);
  deleteDC(tx);

  sz.cx := h.biWidth;
  sz.cy := h.biHeight;
  p := Point(0,0);

  BlendFunction.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
  BlendFunction.BlendFlags := 0;
  BlendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
  BlendFunction.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;

  frm := TForm.CreateNew(self);
  frm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  frm.Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
  frm.Show;

  UpdateLayeredWindow(frm.Handle, 0, nil, @sz, bmp, @p, 0, @BlendFunction, ULW_ALPHA);
end;
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I don't get it: why don't you use a TLable on the transparent form?

Comment: Try to use a font like TAHOMA or VERDANA with a transparent form... you will get some border problems because the anti aliased font...

Comment: Maybe the answer to the following question will help you: [How do I put a semi transparent layer on my form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867215/)

Comment: kobik: I setted the transparentcolor to black (I was setting to Fuchsia) and now it's painting as I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use Windows API functions from Delphi (since you've tagged `winapi`), one easy way is:

- `CreateDIBSection()` to create a 32 bit bitmap
- `FillRect()` to fill the background, `DrawText()` to draw the text
- Fix up the alpha
- Use that bitmap with `UpdateLayeredWindow()`

Fixing up the alpha is done by directly modifying the bitmap bits that you get back from `CreateDIBSection()`. Note that `UpdateLayeredWindow()` requires pre-multiplied alpha, so you have to multiple the RGB components by the alpha value in advance.

The following code is C but hopefully will give you the idea:

```
LPVOID pBits; // bits from CreateDIBSection
const int width, height; // size of bitmap
const int alpha; // level of transparency

RGBQUAD* pPtr = (RGBQUAD*)pBits;
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
     for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x, ++pPtr)
     {
        pPtr->rgbBlue = (alpha * pPtr->rgbBlue) / 255;
        pPtr->rgbGreen = (alpha * pPtr->rgbGreen) / 255;
        pPtr->rgbRed = (alpha * pPtr->rgbRed) / 255;
        pPtr->rgbReserved = alpha;
     }
}
```