# Display TPanel as Modal

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog, panel

I have a main form, with multiple panels, some of which are hidden.  As the user interacts with the main form, I need to make some of the hidden panels visible and display them in a modal fashion so the user can't interact with the other parts of the main form until they finish with the *modal panel*.

Is there a way to display an existing panel on a form in a modal fashion?

I would prefer to **not** cycle through the main forms controls and disable/hide everything except for the one panel, which is the common answer developers have given when others have asked this same question.

My goal is to simply display an existing panel on the main form in a modal fashion without having to manipulate the other controls on the main form.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I put a semi transparent layer on my form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867215/). Answers show how to display a semi-transparent modal overlay on top of a TForm while allowing specific controls to show through the overlay. You could use a similar technique, but construct the overlay TForm in code rather than use a DFM. Then you can show the panel and then show the overlay to block interaction with the panel's Form until the panel is hidden and the overlay is closed.

Comment: How does the user change panels? can't you not just control the conditions that allow them to move back or forth?

Comment: @JohnKouraklis - Possibly, but in this case, the hidden panels have several parts that change as the user interacts with the rest of the form.  Users can click a series of buttons to activate one of the hidden panels as needed.  For our use case, this works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `TForm` has `.ShowModal()`, we can easily create a temporary form, move the `TPanel` to the form, display the form as modal, wait for the user to dismiss the form, then move the `TPanel` back to its original parent before destroying the `TForm`.

If you create a form with a hidden `TPanel` called *pnl* and a button on that panel called *btnCloseModalPanel*, then the following code displays *pnl* as modal until the user clicks the button.

```
begin
  DisplayModalPanel(pnl);
  // do something with 'pnl.data...'
end;

procedure TForm1.DisplayModalPanel(Panel: TPanel);
var
  frm: TForm;
  old_top, old_left: Integer;
  old_parent: TWinControl;
  old_visible: Boolean;
begin
  frm := TForm.Create(Panel.Parent);
  try
    frm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
    frm.Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
    frm.Tag := 12921; // test in close button click, so we don't close the wrong form

    // Rememer properties we can change and then restore them
    old_top := Panel.Top;
    old_left := Panel.Left;
    old_parent := Panel.Parent;
    old_visible := Panel.Visible;

    // Move the panel to the modal form
    Panel.Parent := frm;
    Panel.Top := 0;
    Panel.Left := 0;
    Panel.Visible := True;

    // Display the modal form
    frm.AutoSize := True;
    frm.ShowModal;

    // Restore everything
    Panel.Visible := old_visible;
    Panel.Parent := old_Parent;
    Panel.Left := old_left;
    Panel.Top := old_top;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(frm);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnCloseModalPanelClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm: TForm;
begin
  if pnl.Parent is TForm then
  begin
    frm := pnl.Parent as TForm;
    if frm.Tag = 12921 then // don't close the wrong form
      frm.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Rather than doing all the flip-flopping with the panel's `Parent` (which invokes side effects), I would simply put the panel on a TForm and leave it there all the time. Keep the TForm hidden when not used, and show it modally when needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - What are the side-effects of changing the Parent? I see the OldForm.RemoveControl() and NewForm.InsertControl(), and UpdateAnchorRules(), but nothing else. Is there something that I should be worried about?

Comment: I would have to look at it again, but off the top of my head, I seem to recall that it causes window recreations and control realignments, etc. If the panel is hidden when its parent is changed, all that overhead still happens even though the user doesn't see it happening visually.

Comment: The questio asks how to achieve this without using a form.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I meant "without creating a new form just for the one modal panel to be compiled into the application".  I have many hidden panels on the form, each is used when needed.  The user should finish with the panel before returning to the form.  I already have dozens of forms.  If I could elevate a single panel to a modal display, I can avoid having to create dozens of additional small forms just to give me the ability to display them as modal.  Displaying an existing panel via a temp form is a viable and acceptable solution, unless someone has a better way to do it.

Comment: You did create a new form. TForm.Create is right there in the code.

Comment: Well, it's semantics really.  I don't mind creating a dynamic form at runtime.  I don't want to design dozens of small forms that are all embedded as separate forms in the compiled application.  Having a way to include the panels on the master form, and simply display a single panel briefly in a modal fashion has several advantages in our particular situation.  I've seen the question asked elsewhere many times, the answer always very complex.  This just seemed like a simple way to do what others have wanted, and I thought I'd share it.

Comment: The key is that you don't want to design these forms. That's not clear from the question.

Comment: You are right, sorry for the confusion.  I will reword the question.

Comment: If it is just a panel holder why not create a template form to inherit from. Then add the forms but take them out of the auto-generate. They wont take much room in the exe. The only overhead really is the default values stored for loading.

Comment: I read the question asking not without using a form, but not compiling a form into the executable. I have no idea why such a requirement would exist, but as this answer addresses the issue, +1.

Comment: I find the "tag" bit unjustifiable though.. It's your code parenting the panel, the panel will not get accidentally parented by a rogue form.

Comment: Looks like you've re-invented frames.