# How to make all of components blurred like Chrome's settings menu when SplitView menu is opened in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, overlay, panel, splitview

My question is too long, I am sorry for that.

I added a SplitView component to my Delphi app. When the hamburger menu button is clicked, the splitview is opened.

But I want to overlay grayish transparent layer onto another components (panel, button etc.)

When the grayish layer is clicked, the splitview menu will be closed and another components will be accessible to the user.

I want to like this:

[image]

I could not do this myself; because TGraphic derived controls like TImage can not be front of the panel and buttons.

What should I do?

Comment: Place a borderless semi-translucent TForm over the area you want to grey out

Comment: A borderless form seems like too much. I've done the same with a plain old `TPanel`. Think about when the user goes to move or re-size the main form. You'd have to code the other one to "follow" it. Then just make the panel translucent and drop whatever you need inside of it.

Comment: [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11896840/8041231)?

Comment: @JerryDodge except you can't make a child control translucent via the Win32 API prior until Windows 8, unless you draw it manually. Is that what you did with your Panel?

Comment: @Triber, Victoria Thanks for that. I knew I already posted an answer for a similar issue before, but I couldn't find it this time

Comment: @Remy I was assuming this was Firemonkey given the use of `TSplitView`, but it appears there's a VCL version of that control too. As of now, we don't know which framework OP is using.

Comment: @JerryDodge "*... **TGraphic** derived controls like TImage...*" - `TGraphic` and `TGraphicControl` do not exist in FireMonkey, only in VCL.